# Theano custom Op for PyMC3

Tags: function, theano, pymc3

I tried to implement a custom Op to which I get the "Bad input argument to theano function" error. Here is the code. The problem as I understand is: how to convert the PyMC3 variables into theano understandable type?

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as t
from theano import config
config.compute_test_value = 'off'

#true_Data = [1,2]
#values=[]

class trial_Op(theano.Op):
    __props__ = ()
    itypes = [t.dmatrix, t.dmatrix, t.dmatrix]
    otypes = [t.dmatrix]

    def perform(self,node,inputs,output_storage):
        x0 = inputs[0]
        x1 = inputs[1]
        x2 = inputs[2]
        z = output_storage[0]
        z[0] = np.add(x0,x1)
        z[0] = np.add(z[0],x2)

    def grad(self,inputs,output_grads):
        return output_grads[0]
Trial_Op = trial_Op()

x1 = t.dmatrix()
x2 = t.dmatrix()
x3 = t.dmatrix()
f = theano.function( [x1,x2,x3], trial_Op()(x1,x2,x3) )

# the Op works for the 
#inp1 = np.random.rand(3,1)  # a 2d matrix
#inp2 = np.random.rand(3,1)  # a 2d matrix
#inp3 = np.array([[-40]])                # a constant
#print("Op application gives = ", f(inp1,inp2,inp3))


import pymc3 as pm
true_Data = [[1]]

with pm.Model() as model:
    x1 = pm.Normal('x1', mu = 0, sd = 0.1)
    x2 = pm.Normal('x2', mu = 3, sd = 0.5)
    x3 = np.asarray([[4]], dtype='float64')
#    x1 = x1.reshape(1,1)
#    x2 = x2.reshape(1,1)
    sum_of_x1_x2_x3 = f(x1,x2,x3)
    z = pm.Normal('z', sum_of_x1_x2_x3, observed = true_Data)
    start = {'x1':[[0.1]], 'x2':[[0.1]]}
    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(100, step, start)

pm.traceplot(trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer your question.

**Firstly**, you should not use `f = theano.function( [x1,x2,x3], trial_Op()(x1,x2,x3) )`. Once it defined, `f` takes numeric values as arguments. However in the pymc3 model, `x1` and `x2` defined as `Normal` are not numeric but symbolic. So it will throw the error you just faced. If you are familiar with *`@as_op`* method documented in the tutorial, the solution is simple: change `sum_of_x1_x2_x3 = f(x1,x2,x3)` to `sum_of_x1_x2_x3 = Trial_Op(x1,x2,x3)` ;

**secondly**, in your code, it seems `dmatrix` type is not necessary. so I modify the code following:

```
N = 20 #data array length

class Trial_Op(theano.Op):
    __props__ = ()
    itypes = [t.dscalar, t.dscalar]
    otypes = [t.dvector] #if the data has multiple values i.e. data array

    def perform(self,node,inputs,output_storage):
        x0 = inputs[0]
        x1 = inputs[1]

        f = np.add(x0,x1)
        out = np.empty(N)
        out[:] = f
        z = output_storage[0]
        z[0] = out


trial_Op = Trial_Op()


import pymc3 as pm
true_Data = np.random.normal(2,1,N)

with pm.Model() as model:
    x1 = pm.Normal('x1', mu = 0, sd = 0.1)
    x2 = pm.Normal('x2', mu = 3, sd = 0.5)    

    mu = trial_Op(x1, x2)
    z = pm.Normal('z', mu = mu, sd = 1., observed = true_Data)

    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(10000, step)

pm.traceplot(trace)
```

Note in the custom function, the `otypes` is `dvector` to satisfy the `mu` in the  `z = pm.Normal('z', mu = mu, sd = 1., observed = true_Data)`. And the sample number expands to 10000. The result image shows:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMTkz.png)

**However**, I don't know how to define the *`grad()`* method in the custom theano function. Maybe later someone or me can solve it to enable NUTS sampling method in the model :).